C# FoxPro проблема с русскими символами
Сделал выборку FoxPro
(
$"{SELECT klient.name, klient.code_kl as Outercode, klient.code_kl as Code, klient.adress as Address, 'Не задан' as responsiblePerson, IIF(ISNULL(GNAME),Name,GNAME) as JuridicalName, Adress as JuridicalAddress, INN FROM klient WHERE exists(SELECT * FROM KNAK WHERE KNAK.code_nak IN (3,4,5,6,8) AND knak.data_vip between DATE({dateFrom.Year},{dateFrom.Month},{dateFrom.Day}) AND DATE({dateTo.Year},{dateTo.Month},{dateFrom.Day})) AND is_deleted=0 ORDER BY NAME ASC}"
)
Русские слова при выборке (JuridicalName, JuridicalAddress, Address, responsiblePerson) преобраруются в нечитаемые символы.
Строка подключения - Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Codepage=1252;Data Source=C:\\Users\\boris\\Documents\\DBFs
Выборка в C# преобразуется в коллекцию объектов с нечитаемыми русскими словами, когда они там встречаются.
В чем может быть причина, и как это исправить?

А почему Codepage=1252? Виндовая русская кодировка 1251. Да и не только русская, вообще кириллица.

Изменил кодировку на 1251, но помогло несильно.
Всё ещё остались строки:
"з/п Splat Professional 100мл Eечебные тdавы"
"з/п Splat Professional 100мл Aиокальций",
"з/п Splat Professional 100мл Iтбеливание пл_с",
"з/п Splat Professional 100мл Oльтdакомплекс"
"з/п Splat Professional 100мл Eиквум-aель"
"з/п Splat Special 75мл Iоdские минеdалы"
"з/п Splat Special 75мл Idaаник"
"з/п Splat Special 75мл Yкстdа отбеливание"
Есть такие строки
"з/п Splat Professional 100мл Зеленый чай",
как видите, без ошибок

При копировании выбранных строк - значений, выглядящих корректно в FoxPro, например, в блокнот или Visual Studio тоже возникают такие же нечитаемые символы.

Хм, интересно. Ну тут мои полномочия всё. Возможно, там вообще какая-то своя самописная кодовая страница. Или специальный шрифт с другими буквами. Я даже не знаю.

Вероятно данные были записаны в неверной кодировке в базу или повреждены. Либо поищите другие провайдеры кроме Provider=VFPOLEDB.1, от него тоже может зависеть совместимость с данными.

Эти данные (DBF) созданы не мной. Поэтому я исправил это вот так.
Я удалил локальный экземпляр FoxPro и сделал следующее:
using System.Text;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using Dapper;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);

        IEnumerable<string> strings;

        using (OleDbConnection oleDbConnection = new OleDbConnection("Data Source=C:\\Users\\boris\\Documents\\DBFs;Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Codepage=1252;"))
        {
            strings = await oleDbConnection.QueryAsync<string>("SELECT name FROM spisok");
        }

        foreach (string s in strings)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }
}

Спасибо всем, кто пытался помочь.
